# Angular7 Performance

Tags: angular

I've created an angular application. Now I want to do performance check.

Can someone please help to find some tools(not extensions like augury) which can help to identify angular performance issue and generate the report in CVS or excel format.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You need to provide a minimal example and share what you have done so far or otherwise it means you are asking people to do the research for you.

Answer (score 2):

The best way of testing client-side performance is by profiling the application using browser developer tools 
1. Perform Audit Testing in Developers tool where you get to know your application score in terms of:

> ```
> a.Performance
> b.Progressive Web App
> c.Accessibility
> d.Best Practices
> e.SEO
> ```

try to improve these score definitely, your site performance is increased.
For checking your site performance you can go to google page insight score https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to check time your function call.

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
 yourMethodGenerateCSV();
 var endTime = new Date().getTime();
 console.log('generated time:' + ": " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
```

You also can set start point time and end point time to determine what line of code having performance problem.